# change background opacity with CSS

Tags: css

how I can change opacity of  div background that doesn't make change opacity of text or anything inside of that?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bg">
        <h1>welcome</h1>
        <p>Hello world. Welcome to my site</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



<style>
    .bg{
        background-color: black;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code changes only background opacity

```
.bg{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        color: #ffffff;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to use the RGBa notation, where 'a' stands for alpha (opacity or transparency)?

```
<style>
  .bg {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     color: #ffffff;
   }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bg">
        <h1>welcome</h1>
        <p>Hello world. Welcome to my site</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



<style>
    .bg{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

change only background opacity with rgba

```
.bg{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        color: #ffffff;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy to do using `rgba()` in CSS, but it's something quite a few people don't know about.

Most people know about using `rgb(255,255,255)` instead of `#FFFFFF` to set colours

You can just set the background opacity (which is the opposite of transparency, where 1 is solid and 0 is completely transparent).

```
.bg {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) //This sets background to black, with half transparency
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  .backgorund_opacity {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  /* 0.5 use for opacity ( 0.0-0.9 )*/ 
   }
   </style>
```

**you use also like as**

```
.background {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```